# Remove duplicate data based on date in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to remove duplicate data based on dates. Basically a customer can log in on a website multiple times a day but I want to see one login per customer per day.

Columns:
loginId (always different),
loginTimeStamp,
customerName.

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.a = table2.a
GROUP BY CAST(loginTimeStamp as DATE)
```

I get the error "Star expansion expression references column loginId which is neither grouped nor aggregated at". The error comes up with all the columns. When I load all data without trying to group it it looks fine.

Comment: Which login do you want returned in those cases? Generally you shouldn't try to mix `*` with groups/aggregation.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant with groups/aggregation. And I want just one login per day per customer. So instead of having 10 rows with different loginTimeStamp values and the same name in customerName I just want one row with the earliest loginTimeStamp. Also, when I do not use *, I still get the same error.

Comment: There you go, you want the earliest. When you use `group by` you're aggregating. Each set of rows needs to be collapsed into a single row via an aggregate function if it's not part of the group definition.

Comment: `with data as (select *, row_number() over (partition by CustomerName, cast(loginTimeStamp as date) order by loginTimeStamp) as rn FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.a = table2.a) select * from data where rn = 1;`

Comment: Thank you! I feel this code is very hard to understand, isn't there any other easier way to do this based on the code I pasted?

Comment: *If* your loginids are in ascending order you could use replace `*` with `min(loginId), min(loginTimeStamp)`. You'd also change to `group by CustomerName, cast(loginTimeStamp as date)`, Your general problem is a "top N rows per group" question which has many similar answers if you'd like to explore that.

Comment: Thank you! How can I also display the id? Is there a way? When I add the id column after GROUP BY I get duplicate rows and I cannot use min() there.

Comment: That's why you'll need to tag the entire desired row with `row_number()` and then filter on `rn = 1` if you can't get the value you want from a simple aggregate function. This is the standard approach. You can do a subquery lookup instead by searching on earliest login time but that's not going to be particularly cleaner and definitely not more efficient for the query plan.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your help! Now I started understanding the code you wrote in the start better.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get one row per day and customer, and your loginTimestamp column is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you can group by `customerName` (you can also get number of logins per day with
`count(loginId)`):

```
SELECT customerName, CAST(loginTimeStamp as DATE), count(loginId) 
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.a = table2.a
GROUP BY customerName, loginTimestamp
```

Comment: Tried. It doesn't work, the rows are still duplicate.

Comment: Maybe there is something else in the background... Please confirm format or give an example value for loginTimestamp column. Other possibility of duplication is that column 'a' is not really unique or it is not primary key.

Comment: The first problem is that you're grouping on `loginTimeStamp`. The other part of the problem is that there's still no way to get the `loginId` associated with the earliest timestamp.